# Prolog: Sort a list by alternative index

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I'm attempting to sort a list of colors, by a given preffered order. For example a list [r,z,z,w,g,g,r,z] sorted in this order [z,b,g,r,w], will give an end result of [z,z,z,g,g,r,r,w].
I tried using a basic bubblesort algorithme and adding a check to see which of first two terms would be 'higher' on the order list.

```
% take the to-sorted list, the order in which to sort the list, and the
% result. 
%colourSort([r,z,z,w,g,g,r,z],[z,b,g,r,w],X). returns X = [z,z,z,g,g,r,r,w]

colourSort(List,Order,Sorted):-
    swap(List,List1,Order),
    !,
    colourSort(List1,Order,Sorted).

colourSort(Sorted,_,Sorted).

% check if the either the first or second letter is first in the order
% list, if neither check the next letter in the order list. 
check(A,_,[H|_],A):-
    A == H.
check(_,B,[H|_],B):-
    B == H.
check(A,B,[_|T],R):-
    check(A,B,T,R).
check(_,_,[],_).


%swap incase a set of letters isn't ordered, continues otherwise.
swap([X,Y|Rest],[Y,X|Rest],Order):-
    check(X,Y,Order,R),
    X == R.
swap([Z|Rest],[Z|Rest1],Order) :-
    swap(Rest,Rest1,Order).
```

When I run the code, it ends up crashing my swi-prolog, I'm assuming it's getting stuck in a loop or something, but haven't been able to figure out why or how. 
 Any advice or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: In your very first clause for `colourSort/3`, It calls `swap/3` which then yields `List1` and then you have a recursive call on `coloourSort/3` with `List1`. If `swap/3` doesn't reduce the length of `List1` relative to `List`, then that will recurse infinitely. The logic appears to assume that `swap` will fail if it doesn't end up swapping anything, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: So the loop is causes by it not finding a way out of the swap loop? Still a novice to prolog and build the coloursort of a basic bubblesort, so assumed it would work the same. 

    bubbleSort(List,Sorted) :-
        swap(List,List1), !,
        bubbleSort(List1,Sorted).
    bubbleSort(Sorted,Sorted).

    swap([X,Y|Rest],[Y,X |Rest]) :-
        X > Y.
    swap([Z|Rest],[Z|Rest1]) :-
        swap(Rest,Rest1).

Also seem to suck at pasting code in comments :/

Comment: I don't know if that's your only loop problem, but that's what jumped out at me on first read. If you use `trace` you might be able to see what's going on in detail. -- Pasting code in comments is bad. Unreadable. If you need to elaborate on code, you should edit the question and post it there, properly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution to the stated problem, which does not, however, use a custom sorting algorithm. Instead, it uses the common [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs) data-structure (using the `(-)/2` operator to form a list of items `Key-Value`) and the `keysort/2` for sorting. **Edit:** this answer has been reworked in accordance with @mat's tip in the comments, and to provide a more succinct explanation).

Solution:

```
item_with_rank(Ranking, Item, Rank-Item) :-
    nth0(Rank, Ranking, Item).

sort_by_ranking(Ranking, ToSort, Sorted) :-
    maplist(item_with_rank(Ranking), ToSort, Ranked),
    keysort(Ranked, RankedSorted),
    pairs_values(RankedSorted, Sorted).
```

Explanation:

We define a predicate `item_with_rank(Ranking, Item, Rank-Item)` that uses a list of arbitrarily ordered terms as a `Ranking`, and associates with the given `Item` a `Rank` which is equivalent to the 0-based index of the first term in `Ranking` that unifies with `Item`. We then define `sort_by_ranking(Ranking, ToSort, Sorted)`. `sort_by_ranking/3` uses `maplist/3` to call `item_with_rank/3`, with the given `Ranking`, on each element of the list `ToSort`, obtaining a list of pairs, `Ranked`, assigning a rank to each item. We use `keysort/2` to sort the `Ranked` so that they order of elements accords with the value of their "ranks" (keys) in `RankedSorted`. When we extract just the values from `RankedSorted`, we are left with the `Sorted` items, which is what we were after:

Example of usage:

```
?- sort_by_ranking([z,b,g,r,w], [r,z,z,w,g,g,r,z], S).
S = [z, z, z, g, g, r, r, w] ;
false.
```

Comment: +1, very nice solution! A bit shorter: describing the relation between ranking, item and key-item pair for only a single item as `item_with_rank/3`, and then using `maplist(item_with_rank(Ranking), List, KeyList)`.

Comment: @mat Good call. I'll add that change when I get home. Thanks :)